# What force is needed to slide a plate off a magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have read related the wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets) but I am not able to find a solution to my problem: how to find the min force needed to separate a magnet. I suppose that the force exerted by one magnet is roughly half the force between two [magnets], but the article is above my level and I cannot derive the force from the quoted formulae:

I collected some specifics, can you explain how to use this:
[a $4~in$ disc $2.5~in$ thick](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp) at $1~mm$ has a force of $500~kg$

[image]

**5,001 gauss**,
Grade = N52
Diameter = 4.5"
Thickness = 2.125"
Distance = 3.93700787401575E-02"
**1,041.0 lb**

> [the strength of a 4-in disc (2.5 in thick)](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/fieldcalculator.asp) at 1.5mm distance **at 1° from vertical** is about 1/2T and only 139 gauss on the x axis

[image]

Does this mean that the force needed to slide a magnet horizontally (can we call it shear force) is roughly 1/[20-]30  the vertical force?

Can we say that the force is surely less than 25 Kg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the pull force (perpendicular) is magnetic, the shear force is mainly (or wholly) frictional.  It varies depending on the type and condition of the surfaces, and is typically 10-25% of the pulling force, unless the magnets are coated in rubber or polyurethane when it can be as much as 200%.  There is no reliable way to predict the friction force, so if it is important to know it accurately, you will have to measure it.

The K&J Magnetics app says the pull force between two N52 magnets of the diameter and thickness you specify, is 1200 lb (https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp).  So the shear force will be about 120-300 lb (54-130 kg).

That is the maximum shear force.  As the area of overlap decreases, so will the pull force and therefore the shear force.

https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/Why-does-my-magnet-not-carry-the-maximum-weight-on-the-wall
http://www.eclipsemagnetics.com/row/useful-information-ask-the-expert/

Comment: Thaanks sammy, so if there were a coat of teflon or we prevented the contact the force would negligible. Do you have a curve relating magnetic field to pull force? from my and your examples it seems roughly 10 gauss to 1 Kg, but the ratio is surely not linear

Comment: re Closure : Only 1 reviewer thought it was not a duplicate.  D Hammen has not been prevented from developing a real explanation, he can still do so on the other question. (So can you if you have one.)  I asked him for a better answer.

Comment: re Shear force : yes, that is my understanding - that friction is the only source, so could be negligible with teflon coating.  However, my understanding comes from reading what the engineers have said - I'm not an expert myself, but I presume they know what they are talking about.   I can see that there would be no such component where a magnet slides along a plate, but expected some force when the two attractors uncouple at the edge. I will look into this some more because I'm curious about it myself.

Comment: If you play with their calculator and compare the relative B field in x and specially y axis (see my picture), you can find the relation to the shear force. But the calculator doesn't allow you to go to zero, that's why I mentioned 1mm. If you have a dynamometer and a (/two) magnet you can easily  break new ground